# Object Clean-Up in For-In

Tags: delphi

Will the following code have a memory leak from the TStringlist?

```
function TDemo.GetList:TStringlist;

begin
 Result:=TStringlist.Create;
{...}
end;

procedure TMain.Something;

Var
 S:String;

begin
 For S IN Demo.GetList do begin
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes it will, but don't trust me, check yourself by entering  `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;` in your project file, just before `Application.Initialize;`

Comment: Btw. I don't understand the header in your post. There is no clean-up anywhere.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: The OP probably wonders if Delphi `for in` loops automatically free (clean up) an object created in the `in` part.

Comment: Destroying the TStringList instance after iteration would mean that you never can iterate one twice. Perhaps Wolfgang was mislead by the fact that a dynamically created _enumerator_, which actually operates on the stringlist during the for-in loop, will be freed automatically.

Comment: The language guarantees that the enumerator is cleaned up. But nothing cleans up the collection.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You are right, it's clear now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the `TStringList` will leak.  You must explicitly `Free` the `TStringList` when you are done using it, eg:

```
function TDemo.GetList: TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringlist.Create;
  ...
end;

procedure TMain.Something;
var
  S: String;
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := Demo.GetList;
  try
    for S in SL do begin
      ...
    end;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This is why returning a `Create`'d object as a function return value is usually not a good idea.  In this particular example, returning an array instead would be an alternative solution that doesn't require manual cleanup, eg:

```
function TDemo.GetList: TArray<String>;
begin
  SetLength(Result, ...);
  ...
end;

procedure TMain.Something;
var
  S: String;
begin
  for S in Demo.GetList do begin
    ...
  end;
end;
```